# Display value of the variables

Tags: python, variables, output

Code:

```
score={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5} #value of the alphabet
```

or

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5

word=input('Enter a word:')
word_list=list(word)
for x in word:
  print(x)
```

If i input `bad`

Output:

```
b
a
d
```

Question:How can i put the value of the alphabet beside of it(in the output),like this:

```
b 2
a 1
d 4
```

Comment: So do you have a dict or a bunch of variables? Pick one and ask a clear question.

Comment: 1 more question guys, if i wan to find the sum of the value, can i use sum()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `score` is a dict, you can simply use `x` as an index to get its value:

```
for x in word:
  print(x, score[x])
```

Comment: 1 more question, how can i find the sum of the values?

Comment: That would be `sum(score[x] for x in word)`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it in a general way is with the help of the ord function, which represents the integer value of the letter

```
for letter in ['b', 'a', 'd']:
    print(letter + ' ' + str(ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1))
```

or

```
word = 'test'
for letter in word:
    print(letter + ' ' + str(ord(letter) - ord('a') + 1))
```

This way there's no need for dictionary

Comment: nice. But you can do this with `for letter in word:` too so you have the user input. Also consider using lower()

Answer (score 1):

One-Liner using python 3.6 [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
print("\n".join((f"{score} {scores[score]}" for score in scores))
```

Or if you can't use `f-strings` you can use:

```
print(("\n".join("{} {}".format(score, scores[score]) for score in scores))
```

Comment: lol I was just reading my answer and had "[score for score in seven_years_ago]" pop up in my head. anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop iterates over the keys only. To get the values too, you need

```
for letter, value in score.items():
    print(...)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You're ignoring the user input and just printing the whole dictionary